# Django CBV get list, get object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I've got a simple CBV for all CRUD operations on my model (let's say Book). How should I implement getting object by id and getting a list of all objects? Seems there are many options like:

1. Just create two separate classes Book and BookList.
2. Write some kind of dispatcher inside get method.

   ```
   class BookView(View):
       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           if 'id' in self.kwargs:
               self.get_object(request, *args, **kwargs)
           else:
               self.get_list(request, *args, **kwargs)
   ```
3. Override View.dispatch method so that it will call get_list() method if no id provided.

etc...

So what is best way?

Answer (score 0):

Best way for crud API's is to use [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview) and subclass the `generics.ListCreateAPIView` to get a list of all objects or create new object.

`generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` to get an object by id or to destroy and update the object by id. Like this:

```
class BookDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a book instance.
    """

    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

You will probably have to create your serializers accordingly.

Comment: Isn't it an overkill to use the framework for this? I've got a pretty simple code right now. Anyway I ended up with new class with overridden View.dispatch and inheriting my views from it.